# Can't convert data.frame object to xts object: Gives POSIXlt error. (R)

Tags: r, time-series, xts

I'm trying to convert a data.frame object originating from a .csv to an xts object. Instead of correctly converting to an xts object, it gives the error:

> Error in as.POSIXlt.character(x, tz, ...) : character string is not in a standard unambiguous format

I've tries to change the Date column to the class Date, to no avail. Here is the code:

```
library(xts)
mydata <- read.csv("https://sites.google.com/site/jonspinney/home/mba-6693-2017/edhec.csv?attredirects=0&d=1",header=TRUE,sep=",")
mydata$Date <- as.POSIXlt(mydata$Date, format = "%m/%d/%Y")
mydata <- as.xts(mydata)
class(mydata$Date)
class(mydata)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you call the generic function `as.xts` on a data frame, it is the `xts:::as.xts.data.frame` that will be invoked. By default, it is expecting `row.names` of your data frame to be DateTime, while your `mydata` has its first column as DateTime, and `row.names(mydata)` gives `1, 2, 3, 4, ...` which is certainly not a recognizable string format for `as.POSIXlt` or `as.POSIXct` to convert.

Since you have already arranged the `Date` column into DateTime format (the `POSIXlt` format), you can use `xts` directly:

```
oo <- xts(mydata[-1], mydata[[1]])

str(oo)
#An ‘xts’ object on 1993-12-31/2015-11-30 containing:
#  Data: num [1:264, 1:9] 100 100.4 100.5 99.5 97 ...
# - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
#  ..$ : NULL
#  ..$ : chr [1:9] "CA" "SB" "EM" "EMN" ...
#  Indexed by objects of class: [POSIXlt,POSIXt] TZ: 
#  xts Attributes:  
# NULL

class(oo)
#[1] "xts" "zoo"
```

Answer (score 2):

You can make this a one-liner using `read.zoo` and `as.xts`:

```
myData <- as.xts(read.zoo("https://sites.google.com/site/jonspinney/home/mba-6693-2017/edhec.csv?attredirects=0&d=1",header=TRUE,sep=",", format = "%m/%d/%Y" ))

> str(myData)
An ‘xts’ object on 1993-12-31/2015-11-30 containing:
  Data: num [1:264, 1:9] 100 100.4 100.5 99.5 97 ...
 - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  ..$ : NULL
  ..$ : chr [1:9] "CA" "SB" "EM" "EMN" ...
  Indexed by objects of class: [Date] TZ: UTC
  xts Attributes:  
 NULL
```